# How to draw a customized shape with react-native?

Tags: react-native

Below code is mine

```
 <Animated.View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View style={{ height: '10%', width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'orange', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 26, fontWeight: '600', color: 'black', position: 'absolute', bottom: 10 }}>Dashboard</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%', flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                <View style={{
                    height: '90%', width: '30%', backgroundColor: 'lightgrey', justifyContent: 'center',
                }}>
                    <View>
```

Scroll view that contain multiple view

```
                            <TouchableOpacity style={{
                                width: 200, // top width
                                height: 0,
                                borderBottomWidth: 50, //hight
                                borderBottomColor: "red",
                                borderLeftWidth: 0,
                                borderLeftColor: "transparent",
                                borderRightWidth: 50,
                                borderRightColor: "transparent",
                                borderStyle: "solid",
                            }}>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </ScrollView>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={{
                    height: '90%', width: '70%', backgroundColor: 'lightgrey', 
                    justifyContent: 'center'
                }}>
                    <View>
                        <ScrollView style={{ width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'grey' }}>
                            <TouchableOpacity style={{ height: 100, width: '55%', backgroundColor: '#ffe4c4', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 20, borderTopRightRadius: 30, borderBottomRightRadius: 30 }}>
                                <Text>dfjhxc</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </ScrollView>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </Animated.View>
    )
}
```

[image]

but my code on react-native doesn't work:
I want below design, how can I achieve that?
how we change shape of square as per our requirement?

[image]

Comment: You could add some [transforms](https://reactnative.dev/docs/transforms). It looks like you'll do rotation and maybe skew. [react-native-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg) might save some time if its size and performance isnt an issue.

Comment: After giving it a go I think react-native-svg might be the way

Comment: I worked [this](https://snack.expo.dev/cNj_xnI9B?platform=web) out. If you view it using the web it works perfectly, but it wont draw the polygons on anything else

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/QtTWdRzCb there are still lots of issues

Comment: works on the web but not mobile https://snack.expo.dev/rF0giMsd6

Answer (score 1):

If you use react-native-svg's polygon you can get your desired layout. You just need to know the position of your bar and the position of your text, and then draw your polygon to with those positions. I see you are using a ScrollView, so I assume that the positioning of these views will be moving, meaning that you'll need some animation. react-native-reanimated and react-native-gesture-handler is good for this.

Here's a [demo](https://snack.expo.dev/J6c5IlCHz?platform=android). I started to use typescript, so I hope that's okay

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  LayoutRectangle,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  useWindowDimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { SafeAreaProvider, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

import BarConnectors from './components/BarConnectors';
import ContentItems from './components/ContentItems';
import SideBar from './components/SideBar';

import useBarSharedValues from './hooks/useBarSharedValues';
import useLayout from './hooks/useLayout';

import Colors from './Colors';
import { ITEMS, totalItems } from './Constants';

export default function App() {
  const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();
  // store sideBar's layout to tune pan gesture
  // and calculate itemLayout's x position
  const [sideBarLayout, onSideBarLayout] = useLayout();
  // use textLayout to help calculate itemLayout's y position
  const [textLayout, onTextLayout] = useLayout();
  const [itemLayouts, setItemLayouts] = useState(
    Array(totalItems)
      .fill(null)
      .map(() => ({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0 }))
  );
  const { barY, barRef, ...sharedValues } = useBarSharedValues({
    sideBarLayout,
  });
  // content absoluteY is underneath the Dashboard text
  const contentAbsoluteY =
    Constants.statusBarHeight + textLayout.y + textLayout.height;
  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={styles.container}>
      <SafeAreaProvider style={styles.container}>
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.title} onLayout={onTextLayout}>
            Dashboard
          </Text>
          <View style={styles.row}>
            <SideBar
              {...sharedValues}
              barY={barY}
              ref={barRef}
              sideBarLayout={sideBarLayout}
              onSideBarLayout={onSideBarLayout}
              yOffset={Constants.statusBarHeight}
            />
            <ContentItems
              items={ITEMS}
              itemLayouts={itemLayouts}
              setItemLayouts={setItemLayouts}
              yOffset={contentAbsoluteY}
              color={sharedValues.color}
            />
          </View>
          <BarConnectors
            width={width}
            height={height}
            barY={barY}
            {...sharedValues}
            yOffset={textLayout.height}
            itemLayouts={itemLayouts}
          />
          
        </SafeAreaView>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    opacity: 1,
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 26,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: 'black',
    backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
    textAlign: 'center',
    height: 40,
  },
  circle:{
    position:'absolute',
    width:10,
    height:10,
    borderRadius:5,
    backgroundColor:'pink'
  }
});
```

The sidebar component:

```js
import React, { forwardRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import {
  LayoutChangeEvent,
  LayoutRectangle,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import { Gesture, GestureDetector } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated, {
  SharedValue,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  withTiming,
  useAnimatedProps,
  interpolate,
  Extrapolate,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

import Colors from '../Colors';
import { barSize, barYPosition, sideBarWidth } from '../Constants';
import Svg, { Rect } from 'react-native-svg';
const hitSlop = 120;

type Props = {
  barY: SharedValue<number>;
  sideBarLayout: LayoutRectangle;
  onSideBarLayout: (e: LayoutChangeEvent) => void;
  yOffset: number;
};

// forward ref so that reanimated's measure function can be used
export default forwardRef<Animated.View, Props>(function SideBar1(
  { barY, sideBarLayout, onSideBarLayout, yOffset },
  aRef
) {
  const { height } = sideBarLayout;
  const safeAreaInsets = useSafeAreaInsets();
  // make bar draggable
  const rStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      top: barY.value,
    };
  });

  const pan = Gesture.Pan()
    .onChange((e) => {
      barY.value += e.changeY;
    })
    .onEnd(() => {
      // on release make bar to stay within view dimensions
      barY.value = withTiming(
        interpolate(
          barY.value,
          [-yOffset, height],
          [0, height - safeAreaInsets.bottom - barSize / 2],
          Extrapolate.CLAMP
        )
      );
    });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container} onLayout={onSideBarLayout}>
      <GestureDetector gesture={pan}>
        <View>
          <Animated.View
            style={[styles.bar, rStyle]}
            ref={aRef}
            hitSlop={{
              top: hitSlop,
              left: hitSlop,
              right: hitSlop,
              bottom: hitSlop,
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </GestureDetector>
    </View>
  );
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: sideBarWidth,
    backgroundColor: Colors.lightgray,
    borderRightWidth: 2,
    borderRightColor: Colors.paleOrange,
    zIndex: 40,
  },
  bar: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    width: 3,
    height: barSize,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    top: barYPosition,
    left: 2,
    zIndex: 41,
  },
});
```

render list items and set layout state within them

```js
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, ScrollView, Text } from 'react-native';

import Colors from '../Colors';
import ListItem from './ListItem';
import { sideBarWidth, headerHeight } from '../Constants';

export default function ContentItems({
  items,
  color,
  itemLayouts,
  setItemLayouts,
  yOffset,
}) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header} />
      <View style={styles.content}>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <ListItem
            {...item}
            color={color}
            key={item.id}
            setItemLayouts={setItemLayouts}
            xOffset={sideBarWidth}
            yOffset={yOffset+headerHeight}
          />
        ))}
      </View>
      <View style={styles.footer}></View>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '70%',
    backgroundColor: Colors.darkgray,
    opacity: 1,
  },
  header: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lightgray,
    height: headerHeight,
  },
  footer: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lightgray,
    height: headerHeight,
  },
  content: {
    paddingTop: 5,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: Colors.darkgray,
  },
  layout: {
    width: sideBarWidth / 0.3 / 3,
    padding: 10,
    paddingTop: 0,
    borderRightWidth: 1,
  },
});
```

```js
import React, {
  useCallback,
  forwardRef,
  useEffect,
  useImperativeHandle,
} from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import Animated, {
  useAnimatedRef,
  useAnimatedStyle,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import Colors from '../Colors';
import { headerHeight, itemMarginVertical } from '../Constants';

export default function ListItem({
  title,
  color,
  setItemLayouts,
  index,
  xOffset,
  yOffset,
}) {
  const onLayout = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      const layout = e.nativeEvent.layout;
      if (!layout) return;
      setItemLayouts((prev) => {
        // add on the offsets to get the absolute position
        const newItems = [...prev];
        newItems[index] = {
          ...layout,
          x: layout.x + xOffset,
          y: layout.y + yOffset,
        };

        return newItems;
      });
    },
    [index, setItemLayouts, xOffset, yOffset]
  );
  const rStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    // if useAnimatedColor worked then the backgroundColor
    // would lighten and darken as the bar moved
    return {
      backgroundColor: color.value,
    };
  });
  return (
    <Animated.View style={[styles.container, rStyle]} onLayout={onLayout}>
      <Text>{title}</Text>
    </Animated.View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingVertical: 20,
    backgroundColor: Colors.paleOrange,
    marginVertical: itemMarginVertical,
    width: '50%',
    borderBottomEndRadius: 20,
    borderTopEndRadius: 20,
  },
});
```

Finally, draw the polygons that connect the bars to the list items. This will be by absolutely positioning the svg canvas on top of the screen:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { LayoutRectange } from 'react-native';

import Animated, {
  SharedValue,
  useAnimatedProps,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import Svg, { Polygon as SvgPolygon } from 'react-native-svg';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { sideBarWidth } from '../Constants';
import { MeasuredDimensions } from '../helpers/reanimated';
import Polygon from './Polygon';
const AnimatedPolygon = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(SvgPolygon);

interface Props {
  width: number;
  height: number;
  color: SharedValue<string>;
  barY: SharedValue<number>;
  layouts: SharedValue<MeasuredDimensions>[];
  barLayout: SharedValue<MeasuredDimensions>;
  itemLayouts: LayoutRectange[];
  yOffset: number;
}

export default function BarConnectors({
  width,
  height,
  color,
  layouts,
  barLayout,
  barY,
  yOffset = 0,
  itemLayouts,
}: Props) {
 
  return (
    <Svg
      width={width}
      height={height - yOffset}
      style={[styles.svgContainer, { top: yOffset }]}
      pointerEvents="none">
      {itemLayouts.map((layout, i) => {
        return (
          <Polygon
            itemLayout={layout}
            layout={layout}
            barLayout={barLayout}
            index={i}
            key={`polygons-${i}`}
            color={color}
            barY={barY}
            yOffset={yOffset}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Svg>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  svgContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    // backgroundColor: 'red',
    // opacity:0.25,
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    zIndex: 100,
  },
});
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import Animated, {
  SharedValue,
  useAnimatedProps,
  useDerivedValue,
  runOnUI,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import { LayoutRectangle } from 'react-native';
import { Circle, Polygon as SvgPolygon } from 'react-native-svg';
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { segmentSize, barYPosition, itemMarginVertical } from '../Constants';

import { initialBarLayout } from '../hooks/useBarSharedValues';
import { MeasuredDimensions, measureView } from '../helpers/reanimated';
import Colors from '../Colors';

const AnimatedPolygon = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(SvgPolygon);
// eslint-disable-next-line
const AnimatedCircle = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Circle);

interface Props {
  itemLayout: LayoutRectangle;
  layout: SharedValue<MeasuredDimensions>;
  barLayout: SharedValue<MeasuredDimensions>;
  index: number;
  color: SharedValue<string>;
  barY: SharedValue<number>;
  yOffset: number;
}

export default function Polygon({
  index,
  color,
  barLayout,
  barY,
  itemLayout,
}: Props) {
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
  // animate point changes when barLayout changes
  const points = useDerivedValue(() => {
    console.log('recalculating polygon points')
    let p = '';
    const bLayout = barLayout.value || initialBarLayout;
    // if you use barLayout.value.pageY you get the absolute y position
    // but its value doesnt update

    // if you use barY.value its isnt the absolute y position
    const barPoint = barY.value + segmentSize * index + insets.top;
    const itemPageX = itemLayout.x;
    const itemPageY = itemLayout.y;
    p =
      `${itemPageX},${itemPageY + itemLayout.height} ` +
      `${itemPageX},${itemPageY} ` +
      `${bLayout.pageX},${barPoint} ` +
      `${bLayout.pageX}, ${barPoint + segmentSize / 2} `;

    return p;
  }, [itemLayout,barY.value,barLayout.value]);
  const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps(() => {
    return {
      // fill: color.value,
      points: points.value,
    };
  });
  return (
    <AnimatedPolygon fill={Colors.paleOrange} animatedProps={animatedProps} />
  );
}

// export default Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Polygon);
```